# How to center everything in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an JSP page and I'm trying to center everything. I have following HTML script below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    body{text-align:center}

</style>

<body>

    CONTENT HERE!<br>
My name is XXXX, and please call me XX.


</body>
</html>
```

When testing in web browser, it does center but the the beginning of each sentence is not aligned. How do I adjust it?

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 4):

You want to insert a container and center that.
[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcLFz/)

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    CONTENT HERE!<br>
    My name is XXXX, and please call me XX.
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 70%;     /* specify a width! */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not center your every content when you do text-align property in body. But you try these properties :

```css
margin: auto; 
display: flex;  
justify-content: center; /* for horizontal */
align-items: center; /* for vertical */
```